# How to use Round Function with groupBy in Pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

How can we use the Round function with Group by in pyspark? i have a spark dataframe through which i need to generate a result by using group by and round function??

```
data1 = [{'Name':'Jhon','ID':21.528,'Add':'USA','ID_2':'30.90'},
{'Name':'Joe','ID':3.69,'Add':'USA','ID_2':'12.80'},
{'Name':'Tina','ID':2.48,'Add':'IND','ID_2':'11.07'},
{'Name':'Jhon','ID':22.22, 'Add':'USA','ID_2':'34.87'},
{'Name':'Joe','ID':5.33,'Add':'INA','ID_2':'56.89'}]

a = sc.parallelize(data1)
```

In SQL query will be like

```
select count(ID) as newid, count(ID_2) as secondaryid, round(([newid]+
[secondaryid])/[newid]* 200,1) AS [NEW_PERCENTAGE] FROM DATA1
groupby Name
```

Comment: That doesn't appear to be a valid SQL query

Comment: @BigDataLover if you found my answer useful please consider giving it an upvote besides accepting it, thanks :)

Comment: i have already done that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `round` inside a `groupby`, you need to create a new column afterwards:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame(a)

(df.groupby('Name')
   .agg(
     F.count('ID').alias('newid'),
     F.count('ID_2').alias('secondaryid')
   )
   .withColumn('NEW_PERCENTAGE', F.round(200 * (F.col('newid') + F.col('secondaryid')) / F.col('newid'), 1))
).show()

+----+-----+-----------+--------------+
|Name|newid|secondaryid|NEW_PERCENTAGE|
+----+-----+-----------+--------------+
| Joe|    2|          2|         400.0|
|Tina|    1|          1|         400.0|
|Jhon|    2|          2|         400.0|
+----+-----+-----------+--------------+
```